# Error Message During the Installation of Microsoft Visual c++ 2015

Tags: windows, visual-c++, installation

I have problem trying to install visual c++ 2015. All I  get is error  Message. The error message is 0x80240017. I have tried several solutions provided online but it seems none of them is working for me. Some will tell me to fully uninstall then restart my PC and try to do the installation again. 
I'm running windows 7 32bit. 
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your PC?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I have reboot my system several times. 
The error message is:
0x80240017

Comment: I don't know if it is aplies also to VS2015, but older versions have problems when you had installed newer version of runtime redistributable then included in VS installer. I would give it a try, uninstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 redistributable a try installation again. If it fails and other programs stop working, it could be reinstalled from [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True)

Answer (score 1):

I'm very grateful to everyone.
I found the solution to my problem. The specifications of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 indicate that your Operating System must have a Service Pack. Eg service pack 1 for win7.

You can check this by checking the properties of my computer. Right under the operating system it will be indicated if you have a service pack or not.

To get a service pack for windows 7 try to check for updates. Make sure you see service Pack 1. Or whatsoever. If not install the updates available and restart your PC then check for updates again. Then it should be there.

Thanks house for your contribution